# Update a table based on values from a other table

Tags: sql, oracle

It's rather simple, I want to update a table but only if a condition in a other table is met. 
The query i currently have:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.value='1234'
WHERE   ID IN 
(   
  (A sub query returning all the id's needed) 
)
```

This sort of works, but it updates to many values.
Problem is that there is a second condition, namely:

```
AND Table2.value = 'Pudding'
```

But seeing it's a different table it doesn't work. And i don't know how to join it in Oracle. Seen some other posts but they don't seem to relate to my specific problem. Tried adding the From clause with joins that i also use in the sub-query but i can't find here to put it in an update statement in oracle.

Edit: Example database

Table1

```
ID    Key1     Key2     Value
1    A1       B1       345
2    A1       B2       75
3    A2       B1       45
```

Table2

```
Key1     Key2     Value
A1       B1       'Pudding'
A1       B2       'Pudding'
A2       B1       'Something else'
```

And yes the Table2 is also part of the sub-query, but so are about 6 other tables. I believe that listing the entire structure of the sub-query would only be more confusing seeing all it does it bring back a series of Id's which already works fine.

But as result the first two rows in the example need to be updated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I don't see what `Table2` has to do with your query.

Comment: Is the subquery accessing `table2` to get the IDs, or something else? Are the two tables related some how? And yes, sample data would help explain.

Comment: @AlexPoole and Gordon 
I updated the question with a sample of the data and an explanation on why i'm not doing the entire sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm) with subquery like this, becuase there are two columns need to compare in the tables.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET t1.Value = '1234'
WHERE t1.ID IN 
    (   
      --(A sub query returning all the id's needed) 
    ) 
and 
    exists (
     select 1 
     from Table2 t2
     where t1.Key2 =t2.Key2 and t1.Key1 =t2.Key1 and t2.Value = 'Pudding'
    )
```

Here is a sample

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  ID INT,
  Key1 VARCHAR(50),
  Key2 VARCHAR(50),
  Value VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1,'A1','B1','345');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2,'A1','B2','75');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3,'A2','B1','45');

CREATE TABLE Table2(
  Key1 VARCHAR(50),
  Key2 VARCHAR(50),
  Value VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('A1','B1','Pudding'); 
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('A1','B2','Pudding'); 
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('A2','B1','Something else'); 

UPDATE Table1 t1
SET t1.Value = '1234'
WHERE  exists (
 select 1 
 from Table2 t2
 where t1.Key2 =t2.Key2 and t1.Key1 =t2.Key1 and t2.Value = 'Pudding'
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59687/1/0)**:

```
| ID | KEY1 | KEY2 | VALUE |
|----|------|------|-------|
|  1 |   A1 |   B1 |  1234 |
|  2 |   A1 |   B2 |  1234 |
|  3 |   A2 |   B1 |    45 |
```

Comment: This works, but i have a little question. I've never used Exists before and wonder why the "Select 1"? what function does that have?

Comment: `TRUE if a subquery returns at least one row`.  `select 1` 
 mean the condition match  in the subquery.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm`